# Cup product graded commutative elementary example

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to get some intuition about the cup product for singular cohomology and was trying to check whether the graded commutativity $\varphi\smallsmile \psi = (-1)^{kl}\psi \smallsmile \varphi$ for $\varphi \in H^k(X)$ and $\psi \in H^l(X)$ is obvious for small $k,l$.

The most elementary case is when $k,l$ are both zero. Then $\varphi \smallsmile \psi$ is simply the pointwise product (where we may view the cocycles $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as functions on $X$) and the formula is immediate.

The next case is the product of a $0$-cocycle $\varphi$ with a $1$-cocycle $\psi$. The $1$-cocycle $\varphi \smallsmile \psi $ assigns to any $1$-simplex, which is to say curve, $f:\sigma_1 \to X$ the value $\varphi(f(1,0)) \psi(f)$. Similarly $\psi \smallsmile \varphi$ is the $1$-cocycle which assigns $\varphi(f(0,1))\psi(f)$ to any curve $f$. So we have that $\varphi \smallsmile \psi = \psi \smallsmile \varphi$ assigns the value $(\varphi(f(1)) - \varphi(f(0)))\psi(f)$ to $f$. That $\psi\smallsmile \varphi - \varphi \smallsmile \psi = 0$ in cohomology is now equivalent to this value only depending on the endpoints of the curve but I don't see why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are homologous via $f$, so that $\varphi(f(0))-\varphi(f(1))$ is zero for any $f$.

---

The usual way to see that the cup-product is graded commutative is as follows:

Note that the value of a $1$-cocycle on a $1$-simplex $f$ is turned into its opposite if you reverse the orientation of $f$. Let's denote by $-f$ the simplex $f$ with opposite orientation.

$$\begin{eqnarray}(\varphi\smallsmile \psi)(f)&=&-(\varphi\smallsmile \psi)(-f)\\ \varphi(f(0))\psi(f)&=&-\varphi(f(1))\psi(-f)\end{eqnarray}$$
Now use again that $\psi(-f)=-\psi(f)$ to conclude.

Comment: I don't understand why it follows from $\psi$ being a cocycle that $\psi(f)$ only depends on the endpoints of $f$. This seems to assume all cocycles are coboundaries.

Comment: @A.VanWerde Sorry I was tired yesterday.